# Rest Webservice in Magento - Access Denied

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.8, I have a problem in Rest webservice.

I am trying to get order details using this link http://domainname.com/magento_new/api/rest/orders/100000040 and it shows me access denied error

```
<magento_api>
   <messages>
      <error>
         <data_item>
           <code>403</code>
           <message>Access denied</message>
         </data_item>
      </error>
   </messages>
</magento_api>
```

For retrieving Product details it works (http://domainname.com/magento_new/api/rest/products/11). I have given all permissions in Rest Roles and Attributes. Please any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the url with the increment order id. You need to use the order id (table increment key).

So you need something like this:  `http://domainname.com/magento_new/api/rest/orders/23`.
Also, if you are logged in as a customer you will only have access to your orders.
Only as admin you have access to all the orders.

Comment: I have loggged in backend admin panel but still same problem

Comment: Sorry. I didn't make it clear enough. You are not supposed to log in the admin panel. You should login in the REST api using OAuth, but log in as an administrator. See this example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-CreateasimpleproductasanAdminuserwithOAuthauthentication